# Beginner Friendly game for my friends and I. (No experienced GM)

Tags: game-recommendation, new-gm, new-players

My three friends and I are very interested in playing Table-top rpg's but we're having some trouble getting started. We're looking for a pretty beginner friendly game that doesn't require an experienced GM to have a good time. None of us have ever played a table-top but I've listened to a few play sessions of various games. I'll probably be the GM but it all seems daunting.

So what we're looking for is...

- Beginner Friendly
- Able to play and have fun with no experience GM
- Not too rule heavy? (Easy to teach and learn)
- Not too heavy on the budget (we're all college students)

Comment: Welcome! We've already answered a question much like this one (linked in your question.) When you register and get some rep, we can help you craft an appropraite game-recommendation question in [chat].